# ubuntu 16.04 can't add 1080p mode to xrandr asus VS247H-P, nvidia

Tags: ubuntu, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, xrandr

I asked this already on ubuntu forums but have been unable to find a solution, see:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2341827

My 1080p monitor is stuck at 1360x768 resolution in ubuntu 16.04. I've tried to add a new mode to xrandr but end with this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  45
  Current serial number in output stream:  46
```

SPECS

Monitor: Asus VS247H-P

Cable: amazon basics hdmi

graphics card: gigabyte windforce gtx970

driver: nvidia-367 (have tried it with multiple nvidia drivers)

Here's the full method I'm trying.

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1360 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00 +
   1360x768      59.96*   59.80  
   1152x864      60.00  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   680x384       59.96    59.80  
   640x480       59.94  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       72.19  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)



cvt 1920 1080# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync



xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "1920x1080_60.00"X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  45
  Current serial number in output stream:  46
```

I'm fairly new to ubuntu so I'm not sure which parameters are invalid. Also, if I get this to work how would I make it persist through startup?

Comment: This is a random shot into dark - but try to generate the mode with lower frequency using `gtf`. Try 59 or 55 Hz. I recall that helped someone with same issue - it was intel driver though.

Comment: http://arachnoid.com/modelines/ provides a slightly different modeline: Modeline "1920x1080_60.00" 172.80 1920 2040 2248 2576 1080 1081 1084 1118 -HSync +Vsync

Comment: If the answer doesn't work - you may have to edit `xorg.conf`. See example at link above. See also http://askubuntu.com/a/334404/73056

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

or:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 172.80 1920 2040 2248 2576 1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync
```

followed by:

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr --output  HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

The syntax difference being the quotes around the mode for `--addmode` and `--output`.

Otherwise - see related answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/334404/73056 and edit xorg.conf to add Modlines.